# How to detect, if something is not working properly?

Tags: raspbian, power-supply

I've bought a Raspberry PI 2 a month ago. Everything worked fine. I've reinstalled it sometimes.

But I've noticed that now it's slower than before, and freezes more often. Is it a program, using I could test, if something is not working properly?

I use a 8GB microSD, and 0.7A power supply from the beginning.

Comment: It could be program, yes. If it's a fresh installation, something on power supply side could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure about the 0.7A power supply value? For a RPi2, you need a Switch power supply of at least 1.5A (though my experience has been that 2A+ is best if you have multiple USB devices (keyboard, mouse, WiFi))

Comment: SD card problem. I have experienced this allot! I bought some Samsung Evo (oragne) ones, tested they not fake.. they run really good. I did allot of research to find this one and its a good one. I must have like 20 working.. but slow SD cards now, various makes, Kingston, no brand, other brand.... its a nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the performance sluggish sometimes, the first thing you should check is to see if the CPU is running up and/or something has hogged the RAM.

There are various common simple tools for this purpose; two of the more popular ones that can be used sans GUI (e.g., via `ssh`) are `free` and `htop`.  The former will show something like this:

```
> free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         976500       32912      603936       12572      339652      909168
Swap:             0           0           0
```

The critical number here is `available` -- also note that this version of `free` may be newer than the default Raspbian one and show output in a slightly different format, but the concepts are the same.  The OS will use free RAM for caching to improve performance, and this can be confusing with regard to the numbers.  Here, I have 32912 KiB actually committed (`used`), but the kernel has stashed 339652 KiB of [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (`buff/cache`) and this is subtracted in the `free` number, which other tools also use, possibly making it *seem* like running processes have used 360 MiB+ here.

However, when more free RAM is needed the OS will ditch the cache, so the actual amount used by running processes is really just the `used` figure (~32 MiB).

[`htop`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) is a sort of spin-off of a venerable *nix tool, `top`, which may be more useful than the latter particularly on multicore systems.  A few of the important things you can get from this:

- The current CPU usage.
- Which process is using the most CPU, and how much it is using.

The limitation here is it's only the current moment.  There are GUI monitors that will show a graph going back in time slightly -- two popular ones are `conky` and `gkrellm`.

Finally, for checking the logs for error/warnings, in addition to Patrick's suggestion about `dmesg`, you can check:

- `tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog` on SysV init systems (Raspbian 7, wheezy)
- `journalctl | tail -n 50` on systemd systems (Raspbian 8, jessie, the current version).

See `man tail` and `man journalctl` (and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) if you don't know what a man page is yet).

Answer (score 1):

The command `dmesg` will show what the kernel was doing and at what time, you can use this command to find at exactly what time the system crashed, and what program/command was run last (which would most likely be the reason for the crash)

EX:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dmesg
... #I'll skip the unimportant stuff
[  242.439140] Transfer to device 13 endpoint 0x1 frame 469 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
```